# Building Linux Driver Failed in 5.4, patch fixed, now 5.10 no longer builds with patch adjusted "No rule to make target"

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kbuild

I have a Linux driver I've been building since 3.x days, 4.x days, when hitting 5.4 it broke the build but I found a patch that fixed it.  Now moving to 5.10 (jumped over the others), it's no longer working even with the patch applied (Hunk #1 needed to be adjusted for the changes in the 5.10.19 Makefile.build and now completes with fuzz, Hunk #2 completed from original patch with fuzz). The patch below is the adjusted patch applied to 5.10.19.  The problem is

> "No rule to make target '/path/to/sourcefile.o', needed by
> '/path/to/lib.a' Stop

The build builds a common library for all drivers which then ends up linking to build the specific driver.

I build on Debian GNU/Linux 8.11 (jessie).  Here's the patch that worked on 5.4 (adjusted for 5.10.19):

```
diff --git a/scripts/Makefile.build b/scripts/Makefile.build
index b734ac8a654e..a8481b765ea8 100644--- a/scripts/Makefile.build
+++ b/scripts/Makefile.build
@@ -265,8 +265,10 @@ $(obj)/%.o: $(src)/%.c $(recordmcount_source) $(objtool_dep) FORCE
    $(call if_changed_rule,cc_o_c)
    $(call cmd,force_checksrc)
 
+multi-m-prereqs = $(addprefix $(obj)/, $($*-objs) $($*-y) $($*-m))
+
 cmd_mod = { \
-   echo $(if $($*-objs)$($*-y)$($*-m), $(addprefix $(obj)/, $($*-objs) $($*-y) $($*-m)), $(@:.mod=.o)); \
+   echo $(if $(multi-m-prereqs), $(multi-m-prereqs), $(@:.mod=.o)); \
    $(undefined_syms) echo; \
    } > $@
 
@@ -427,13 +429,13 @@ targets += $(obj)/lib-ksyms.o
 endif
 
 # NOTE:
-# Do not replace $(filter %.o,^) with $(real-prereqs). When a single object
+# Do not replace $(multi-m-prereqs) with $(real-prereqs). When a single object
 # module is turned into a multi object module, $^ will contain header file
 # dependencies recorded in the .*.cmd file.
 quiet_cmd_link_multi-m = LD [M]  $@
-      cmd_link_multi-m = $(LD) $(ld_flags) -r -o $@ $(filter %.o,$^)
+      cmd_link_multi-m = $(LD) $(ld_flags) -r -o $@ $(multi-m-prereqs)
 
-$(multi-used-m): FORCE
+$(multi-used-m): $(obj)/%.o: FORCE
    $(call if_changed,link_multi-m)
 $(call multi_depend, $(multi-used-m), .o, -objs -y -m)
```

Is there a new patch for 5.10 to fix the build of my Linux drivers?

Thanks.

Comment: Why that driver is not in upstream? That is the root cause of your burden...

Comment: it's my own linux driver and even though those are little tiny support lib built at that time it links in a huge library that is needed.  Should I do away with the tiny lib or does someone have a patch / fix for it.  I think I got the original patch off the mailing list, I could go back there, but I tend to unsubscribe due to the number of emails.

Comment: I’m sorry, nobody understands your problem. Linux kernel tested every day by many bots and people with a lot of drivers enabled. If you have a problem with your driver, it is most likely the bug in your code.

Comment: Is that patch being applied to scripts/Makefile.build in the kernel sources? If so, I don't think you should be patching that.

Comment: Yes, that 5.4 patch came from the kbuild group if not the kernel group itself. I think that one had to do with linking with .a libraries.  This is a new one building a library, I guess I'll have to check back there and see if they have something. Or maybe reinstall an old kernel headers and do a comparison of Makefile.build

Comment: Would it be possible to restructure the library as a set of one or more kernel modules with exported symbols?